# python multi plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, plot

I just want to plot the second loop 5 times, but I have a problem with the dimentions. I get this error message that says G and t dosent have the same dimention. G has 450 and t has 50 dimentions.When I set the plot in the second loop, I get that G has size 100 and t has size 50.

```
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import sympy
L=[0.04980905361573844, 0.0208207352451072, 0.012368753716465475, 0.009117292529338674, 0.007461219338976698, 0.006510364609693688, 0.005899506135250773, 0.005485130537183343, 0.0051898472561455]
Lc=[1.7509008762765992, 0.14986486457338544, 0.03453912303580302, 0.014622269851256788, 0.00831141421008418, 0.005660123321843252, 0.004287823173522503, 0.0034922189865254395, 0.0029879534061896186]
beta = 0.25;
G = []
t=np.linspace(0.00000000000001,0.000001,50)
for i in range(len(L)):
    j0 = L[i];
    j1 = Lc[i];
    def f(s):
        return s**(beta - 1)/(j0*s**beta + j1*sympy.gamma(beta + 1))

    for j in range(0,50):
        G.append(mp.invertlaplace(f, t[j], method = 'dehoog', dps = 10, degree = 50))

plt.plot(t,G)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your `for` loop, your not clearing your `G` list between iterations.  Your adding 50 more items to G each time it is run. This is why the dimensions aren't what you are expecting.

EDIT:

You can try something like this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
G = []
solutions = []
t = np.linspace(0.00000000000001,0.000001,50)

for _ in range(len(L)):

    for time in t:
        G.append(time**2)
    
    solutions.append(G)
    G = []

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(5)
ax1.plot(t, solutions[0])
ax2.plot(t, solutions[1])
ax3.plot(t, solutions[2])
ax4.plot(t, solutions[3])
ax5.plot(t, solutions[4])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried to solve it with G[i][j] or something similar, but I could not write the answer . Do you have any idea how I can improve it? @thekid77777

Comment: I think I have it, now. I need to define G in the side of the first loop and plot under second for

Comment: Sure! See my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: And sorry, I thought I read the first time you wanted it all in one plot.  You can ignore the plotting code if you don't want that and like you said, make a new plot then clear `G` at the end of each iteration.